# How to fix "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width" and how to delete an item from a list?

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in Flutter and I can not get the result I want because I have a "layout problem". I tried several things for hours...

**Technical problem:**
When I click on "add player button" to add a new TextField to set more play name, I have an error: "*BoxConstraints forces an infinite width*". So, the TextField isn't displayed.

[image]

**Other features that I do not know how to realize:**
- I have a "dropdownmenu' to choose difficulty game. Why the default text isn't displayed (Difficulty: normal)? 
- How to do this: When the user clicks on the icon "remove" (see suffixIcon on TextField), then the corresponding fieldText is deleted? 
- How to do this: When user click to add player the default HintText is incremented (Player 2, Player 3, Player 4, ....)?
- Why my background gradient doesn't fix when user scroll page? (like in HTML/CSS 'background-attachment: fixed') ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Styles

///




class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<Homepage> {

  String dropdownValue = 'Normal';

  List<TextField> _playerList = new List(); //_playerList is my List name
  int playerListIndex = 0; //Count the number of times "Add" button clicked

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        // To have a gradient background
        new Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 1],
              colors: [
                Colors.redAccent[200],
                Colors.red[300],
              ],
              tileMode:
                  TileMode.repeated,
            ),
          ),

          //I need SingleChildScrollView to haven't "Overflow yellow bar on bottom screen"
          child: SingleChildScrollView(

            child: Container(

              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                  children: <Widget>[
                    // Box to add big image
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 450,
                    ),



                    // DROP DOWN MENU to choose difficulty  modes
                    InputDecorator(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.games),
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: dropdownValue,
                          hint: Text('Difficulty normal'),
                          isDense: true,
                          items: <String>['Normal', 'Easy', 'Hard']
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownValue = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    //Field player name 1. At least I need 1 player
                        new TextField(
                          maxLength: 20,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                            filled: true,
                            hintText:"Player 1",
                            counterText: "",
                          ),
                        ),


                    //Field for other player name 2, 3, 4, ...
                    new ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: _playerList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        TextField widget = _playerList.elementAt(index);
                        return widget;
                      }),

                    //Button to add other field text to set player name. The user can delete a player on click on "clear icon button"
                    new Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: FlatButton.icon(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                          label: Text('Add player',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              playerListIndex++;
                              _playerList.add(
                                    new TextField(
                                      maxLength: 20,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                                        suffixIcon: new IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              _playerList.removeAt(playerListIndex); //Doesn't work
                                            }),
                                        filled: true,
                                        hintText: "Player $playerListIndex", //Doesn't work i would like Player 2, Player 3, ...
                                        counterText: "",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                              );
                              print(playerListIndex);
                              print(_playerList);
                              print(_playerList[0]);
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                    new ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: 350,
                      height: 45,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: Text('Play',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Perform some action
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understood what's going on. Let's begin:

First. Your `TextField` is not showing up and you're getting an error because you didn't set a width and a height for it, so, it's trying to get the maximum size as it can get. Solution for this? Wrap it in a `Container` widget (or `SizedBox`) and give it a width and a height. That should fix the first problem.

Second. Your DropDownMenu's hint text (Difficulty Normal) is not showing because you're not passing the parameter "hint" in the DropDown widget, [See the hint propierty below](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Third. You want to clear the `TextField` string when click on a suffix, right? To achieve this, pass a `GestureDetector` or an `IconButton` as your suffix component, create a `TextEditingController` and pass it in the `TextField`, in the controller section, then, on the onPressed/onTap method (depending on which Widget you'll set) set this: **`_textController.text.clear()`** method, inside the **setState function**. This should fix the problem.

Forth. You want the list of player's string to increase as you add more players right? You have many ways to achieve this, one of them is creating an empty list, you can mock to test it, and then, everytime you click the "Add player" button, you'll add a String corresponding to the value inside a for loop passing the for's index as int value in the "Player $index". Again, the for method will receive a setState method, and inside the setState, your logic to add one more Player.

And finally, your gradient does not keep fixed? Hmm, I think you can pass a proprierty in the Scaffold widget called `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` and set it to false.

If something did not work as you expected, reply it and I'll help you out.

Comment: thank you for your answer I will make the changes and I'll let you know. For Part 3, I would like to remove the textfield and not just clear the text. (remove from the list "_playerList"  the current TextField something like that `playerList.remove (current_index);`(the opposite of the add button functionality)

Comment: I see, if you want to remove, you'll have some workwaround like using setState to verify if some index of the list has been removed, then, change the TextField to an empty Container, I believe in you.

To remove an item from the list, you'll have first to check if it's there on the list, if yes, use .removeAt(index) method and see if it works.

Comment: FYI: I solved the first point, the text fields appear when I click on the add button. But this behavior is stripping: If I scroll from the newly added fields then I can not scroller the page. See update picture with "blue zone".
The second one does not work yet, I added this code hint: Text ('Difficulty normal') ,. I updated source code in first post
Third, I added that _playerList.removeAt (index); but index is not defined.
The fourth, I have not looked for a solution yet.
I continue

Comment: It wont scroll because you have two components with the same behavior: SingleChildScrollView and ListView.builder().

To change the text in the dropdown, you can't pass a hard coded string directly in the Text component, you have to pass like this: Text(myString), then, on the onChanged method inside the DropDown you do:

onChanged: (String value) => setState(() => myString = value);

You'll get the index using the for loop, index, i, the variable name for interate

Comment: Thk i resolved the first point, I added `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`. But i have some difficult to remove an item from _playerList when i click on "X" button

Comment: Again, you want to update your UI removing something, I've already gave you the tip with the setState logic comment above.